# How to make ctype array of string in python3?

Tags: arrays, string, python-3.x, ctypes

I'm trying to pass the list of string (sys.argv) to c library.
In python2.x, it works like :

```
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary("./libfoo.so")

arr = (c_char_p * (len(sys.argv) + 1))(*sys.argv)
arr[ len(sys.argv) ] = None

lib.foo_main(byref(arr))
```

but in python3, it doesn't work and it says :

```
TypeError: bytes or integer address expected instead of str instance
```

So, i fixed it like this :

```
arr = (c_char_p * (len(sys.argv) + 1))()
idx = 0
for arg in sys.argv:
    arr[idx] = bytes(str(arg), 'ascii')
    idx += 1
arr[ len(sys.argv) ] = None
```

But I think this is dirty workaround. I want to know more graceful method.
Can someone help me please?

Comment: Instead of hard-coding ASCII, you can use the filesystem encoding: `arr = (c_char_p * (len(sys.argv) + 1))(*map(os.fsencode, sys.argv))`.

Comment: You don't really need to null the final element since the buffer for the array is initialized to zeros. Also, you don't need to pass an array `byref`. C arrays are passed as pointers.

Comment: In case you're worried about the temporary `bytes` objects, they're referenced in `arr._objects`. So the pointers remain valid as long as the array itself is referenced.